# Add PictureBox to form at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I'm making a C# program that will generate a PictureBox:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
    {
        Name = "pictureBox",
        Size = new Size(16, 16),
        Location = new Point(100, 100),
        Image = Image.FromFile("hello.jpg"),
    };
}
```

However, the control doesn't show up on my form. Why not?

Comment: Unless that image is always going to be located in the same directory as the executable, you should include the full path for that file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can try this..
you need use **this.Controls.Add(picture);**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picture = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "pictureBox",
            Size = new Size(16, 16),
            Location = new Point(100, 100),
            Image = Image.FromFile("hello.jpg"),

        };
        this.Controls.Add(picture);
    }
```

and if you want to remove from form at runtime.

```
 //remove from form
 this.Controls.Remove(picture);
  //release memory by disposing
 picture.Dispose();
```

;

Answer (score 2):

A control, such as a PictureBox, is just a class. There's nothing special about it, so a `new PictureBox` won't magically appear on your form.

All you need to do after instantiating and initializing a control is add the control to the container's Controls collection:

```
this.Controls.Add(picture);
```